# How to put link to the end of text block after 3 dots and animate it on click?

Tags: html, css, animation

CSS:

```
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='text'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
consectetur venenatis blandit. Praesent vehicula, libero non pretium
vulputate, lacus arcu facilisis lectus, sed feugiat tellus nulla eu
dolor. <a>More</a>
</div>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
consectetur venenatis blandit. Praesent vehicula, libero non pretium
vulputate, lacus arcu facilisis lectus, sed feugiat tellus... More
```

and when click on the link text expand with animation. Maybe someone did something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying the full text from a multiple line snippet of the full text, you can add and remove classes to control the size and the ellipsis status.

I’m not sure there’s a way to put your `More / Less` button on the same line as the ellipsis, as `-webkit-line-clamp` ends the text at the end of the line, but you could put the button below the text.

*Note: I’m using a button, rather than a link, as a button is better for accessibility (a link goes somewhere, a button does something).*

`-webkit-line-clamp` doesn’t work in [IE](https://caniuse.com/?search=line-clamp), so you won’t get the ellipsis, but the text block will still expand.

This solution does require setting the max-height of the text box in the CSS in a couple of places (I’ve used 3.375rem for three lines).

```js
function buttonShow(element) {
    var sibling;

    function closed() {
        element.innerText = "More";
        element.parentElement.classList.remove("closing");
        sibling.removeEventListener("transitionend", closed);
    }

    if (element.innerText === "More") {
        element.parentElement.classList.add("show");
        element.innerText = "Less";
        element.setAttribute("aria-expanded", true);
    } else {
        element.parentElement.classList.add("closing");
        element.parentElement.classList.remove("show");
        element.setAttribute("aria-expanded", false);
        sibling = element.previousElementSibling;
        sibling.addEventListener("transitionend", closed);
        element.innerText = "More";
    }
}
```

```css
.text {
    margin-top: 10rem;
    margin: 10rem 5rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    width: 30rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.text p {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    transition: max-height 0.3s ease;
    max-height: 3.375rem;
}

.text button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0.125rem;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.text button:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.text.show p {
    -webkit-line-clamp: 10;
    max-height: 7rem;
}

.text.closing p {
    -webkit-line-clamp: 10;
    max-height: 3.375rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <p id="text-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A suscipit impedit quasi. Fugit qui, debitis, aliquam dolor consequatur nam similique cumque impedit voluptatum saepe soluta repellat incidunt pariatur odit ipsa porro minima quis quaerat perspiciatis quo! Nesciunt doloribus deleniti eius voluptatibus sapiente, rem, cupiditate qui quasi, illo architecto reiciendis explicabo.</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="buttonShow(this)" aria-controls="text-1" aria-expanded="false">More</button>
</div>
```